# Missing fusion cores - how does the Gatling Laser work in regards to fusion cores?

Tags: fallout-4

I used to have around 32 fusion cores, now I only have 18. I didn't use any power armor. I did get a gatling laser, but didn't use much of it because I didn't want to waste fusion cores. How does the weapon actually use the fusion cores, like how much does it waste? Does it take away fusion cores every time I reload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Fallout wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_core):

> "The Gatling laser utilizes fusion cores as its ammunition, each core providing 500 shots."

It also seems as though users have been [complaining on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164594-fallout-4/72845351) that if you reload a fusion core that it's not completely used, you'll waste the charges it has left.

Comment: Well that sucks, but thanks for the info. Probably won't be using the gatling laser now tho.

Comment: They should patch it right? Like the fusion core usage in power armor, which you can still use the used fusion cores.

Comment: I don't think that that forum is saying that any charges will be wasted. All the posts seem to agree with the first one, which says that "otherwise you will be putting partly used cores into your inventory". So you could still use that core to power armor, it's just sitting in your inventory partly used the same as if you took out a nearly drained core. You should be able to sell it for the same caps as a charged one, in which case you should *always* reload your gatling laser before the core is drained.